# Using logarithmic in the objective function in IBM CPLEX

Tags: python, optimization, mathematical-optimization, cplex, docplex

My objective function in IBM CPLEX is as follows:

```
objective = opt_model.sum(math.log(r_vars[0,0]*(3*w_vars[0]-1))+math.log(r_vars[1,0]*(3*w_vars[0]-1)))
opt_model.maximize(objective)
```

The variable `w_vars` can get a value in the range [0,1] and the value of `r_vars` can be in the range of [1,100]. But I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: must be real number, not QuadExpr
```

I assume the problem is the result of the parentheses for the `math.log` function. How can I use a log function in the objective function in IBM CPLEX? Or any thoughts on this?

Comment: Cplex does not do nonlinear programming (with some limited exceptions like quadratic problems or some integer problems). Nonlinear programming problems are almost always better solved with nonlinear programming (NLP) solvers.

Answer (score 1):

What you could do is rely on cpo within Cplex

See

https://github.com/AlexFleischerParis/zoodocplex/blob/master/zoononlinear.py

For a tiny example

```
from docplex.cp.model import CpoModel

mdl = CpoModel(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(0,1000,name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(0,1000,name='nbBus30')
mdl.add(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300)

#non linear objective
mdl.minimize(mdl.exponent(nbbus40)*500 + mdl.exponent(nbbus30)*400)

msol=mdl.solve()

print(msol[nbbus40]," buses 40 seats")
print(msol[nbbus30]," buses 30 seats")
```